# Relink,Relink ALL, and MERGE option is missing under FILES in SPONLINE FORMS Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, view, forms-library

I was trying to relink some records within a form library after migrating to new site and all 3 options RELINK, RELINK ALL and MERGE options was there. later i found those missing and not sure how do i put it back. I am worried if i made any changes or edited view. can someone please assist.

Comment: please provide some screenshots about your issue to understand this issue better.

Comment: @_Kally_MSFT i happen to remigrate the forms library using sharegate and manually relinking all those records. It took me forever but have been able to take care of it. thank you.